# React JS failed to compile invalid left-hand side in array destructuring pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola estoy trabajando con react js, estoy intentando cambiar el insertar, lo tenia con clases y quiero pasarlo a funciones
asi lo tenia
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyzGK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmDnG.png)
y asi estoy intentano cambiarlo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyJAL.jpg)

el formulario
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwRBX.png)

y cuando compilo me sale este error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvVmm.jpg)

me dicen que puede ser por el evento onchange me pueden ayudar a solucionar esta parte porfavor y muchas gracias

Comment: escribe el código, no es bien recibido en el sitio que anexes código como imagen

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes incorrectamente planteada la solución.

1.Para poder agregar valores a un input y almacenarlos en hook `useState` tienes que asignarle como valor inicial un objeto y adentro el nombre del input.

```
const [image, setImage] = useState({
    image: ""
})
```

2.Para poder hacer cambios en el input tienes que usar el `setImage` en una función y agregar la referencia a el input mediante el evento.

```
const cambioValor = (e) => {
    setImage({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}
```

3.En el input agregas en el atributo `name` el mismo nombre que le pusiste en el objeto inicial del `useState` en este caso es `image`.

Nota: No es necesario usar el atributo id en estos casos.

```
<input type="text" name="image" onChange={cambioValor} placeholder='url de la imagen' />
```

Al final tendrías algo como lo siguiente.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const InsertarPromocion = () => {

    const [image, setImage] = useState({
        image: ""
    })

    const enviarDatos = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(image)
    }

    const cambioValor = (e) => {
        setImage({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Agregar Promocion</h3>
            <form onSubmit={enviarDatos}>
                <input type="text" name="image" onChange={cambioValor} placeholder='url de la imagen' />
                <br />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Nota: Te recomiendo usar un customHook para poder manejar el estado de varios inputs sin necesidad de crear varios `useState` y así mejorar un poco el performance.